# Lie algebra of nilpotent Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, nilpotence

Let $G$ be a nilpotent closed subgroup of the group $UT(n,\mathbb{R})$ of upper triangular matrices with $1$-s on the diagonal.

I can construct a Lie algebra from $G$ in two ways:

1. The usual Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group consisting of matrices $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ for which $\exp(tA) \in G$.
2. I can take the lower central series of $G$, take a direct sum of the factors and define Lie brackets in the natural (grading respecting) way.

Are the two Lie Algebras isomorphic? If so, canonically?
(I'm new to this business)

Comment: The second version will not immediately give you a Lie algebra over a field like the first one does (only a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$). And if you don't do some tensoring to correct this, then any finite subgroup will supply a counter example.

Comment: I don't understand your second construction. What's the “natural (grading respecting) way” of defining Lie brackets that you mention? And *where* are you defining them?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This is a standard construction for nilpotent groups. The central series gives a filtration with abelian quotients and one can take the associated graded module corresponding to that, which becomes a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ via the commutator by definition of the series.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. I didn't know it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Won't all factors be isomporphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? How can $G$ be nontrivial finite if it lives in $UT(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Good point on the group not being able to be finite, but I still think you want to include "connected" in your conditions (whereas it is not necessary to require "nilpotent" as that is automatic). Otherwise you could also include for example $\mathbb{Z}$ as a closed subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the Lie algebra (i.e. the first construction) is denoted $\mathfrak{g}$, then the second one will be isomorphic to the associated Carnot-graded Lie algebra $\mathrm{Car}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Since there exist finite-dimensional nilpotent real Lie algebras (in dimension $\ge 5$) $\mathfrak{g}$ that are not isomorphic to their associated Carnot-graded Lie algebra, and since any finite-dimensional nilpotent real Lie algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{ut}(n,\mathbf{R})$ for some $n$, you get a negative answer to your question (at least for $n$ large enough, probably for all $n\ge 4$ actually).